# Dataframe iterate rows eliminate when condition met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big Dataframe, here is the sample data:

```
df['length']
353.216  
353.514  
273.559  
274.199  
353.813  
354.116
```

I want to iterate over the rows and compare the i+1 with i row (and if the difference is less 2, then the value should stay, otherwise the whole row should be filtered out), I tried with Boolean indexing: `diff = abs(df['length']).diff() < 2`  and then `df_clean = df[diff]`

I want to get rid off all 'abnormal' rows. I know that every i+1 row should be in +- 2 range. 
The problem is that there can be more than one row. I want to get rid of 273.559 and 274.199 (in this case), as the difference between them is less 2 I would need to iterate all the rows two times. Including a for loop to iterate over and over again doesn't seem the best approach to me, any good solutions?

Edit: My Output should look as follows:

```
df_clean_data ['length']
353.216  
353.514  
353.813  
354.116
```

Thank you in advance
Ziga

Comment: Can you explain better exactly what you want as output?

Comment: Why only 273.559 and 274.199? There are more contiguous elements with a smaller than 2 distance to surrounding ones, like 353.216  and 353.514

Comment: Only 273.559 (diff = 273.559 - 353.514 = -79.955) and 274.199 should also be eliminated as it exceeds 2 to other 'normal' values (diff = 274.199 - 353.514 = -79.315)

Comment: Please reformulate your question if you want any help, what you are trying to do seems quite unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to success is a function working almost like `diff()`:

```
def mark(x):
    global prevX
    difr = abs(x - prevX)
    result = difr >= 2
    if not result:
        prevX = x
    return result
```

But the differences are that:

1. This function uses a global variable "previous x" (`prevX`),
   containing initially the first `length` (the program has to
   set it).
2. Substitution of the current `x` under `prevX` occurs **only**
   if the difference is less than 2. So, in this respect,
   we "skip" rows to be deleted.

The initial step is to set `prevX` to the 1st length:

```
prevX = df.loc[0, 'length']
```

And the actual processing is performed with a single instruction:

```
df.drop(df[df['length'].apply(mark)].index, inplace=True)
```

A bit of explanation:

- `df['length'].apply(mark)` generates boolean array. `True` means "this row
  is to be deleted". For instruction purpose execute this command alone
  (before dropping).
- `df[...].index` generates list of index values for these rows.
- `df.drop` deletes rows with the given indices (in place).

So the whole script is like below:

```
import pandas as pd

def mark(x):
    global prevX
    difr = abs(x - prevX)
    result = difr > 2
    if not result:
        prevX = x
    return result

data={ 'length': [ 353.216, 353.514, 273.559, 274.199, 353.813, 354.116 ] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
prevX = df.loc[0, 'length']
df.drop(df[df['length'].apply(mark)].index, inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
    length
0  353.216
1  353.514
4  353.813
5  354.116
```

Alternative: If you want the result in another Dataframe, delete
`inplace=True` and substitute the result under the target variable.

Comment: That's an amazing solution, thank you. One more Question: what exactly does  'inplace = True'?

Comment: Without *inplace* the DataFrame with dropped rows is **only the result** of the function and the *df* involved is no changed. But when you use *inplace=True*, the result is saved in this *df*.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not crystal clear, but still whatever I understood I am trying to suggest some way.

1. sort the DataFrame on that column(length)
2. using for loop check for your difference
3. if you want that record add it in the new DataFrame
4. use new DataFrame

other way **Because you have Big DataFrame**

1. sort the DataFrame on that column(length)
2. create new column
3. using for loop check for your difference
4. if you don't want that record write np.nanin the new column
5. remove all the record which contain np.nan in new column